# Not able to boot ubuntu from external hard drive?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04.1 from a bootable usb stick in to seagate external HDD, I am not sure where I am getting steps wrong because after installing ubuntu in my external HDD and when I try to boot it, I am getting the grub rescue cmd prompt screen. I tried doing few steps as seen on the internet but still I am not able to boot it from external HDD.

I am attaching few relevant screen shots of the installation process please help me with this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]